# How to "auto change" status bar text color in android like FB Messenger?

Tags: java, android, statusbar

I see my status bar text color is white but when I open FB Messenger, the color change to black. how can I do that ?

**Before open Messenger**

[image: Before Image]

**When open Messenger**

[image: After Image]

This is my code

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white));

        }


        initViews();



    }
```

Comment: like this,  if (getWindow() != null) {
                                getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.your_color));
                                }

Comment: this is for all API or >=23 ?

Comment: yup, go ahead..

Comment: let me try. I will tell you the result. please write it as an answer. I will mark it if it works

Comment: it will work, and no need to write down an answer, thanks for that

Comment: the status bar is white but the text color is also white @@ it does not change to black

Comment: it should work tran,  clean and rebuild and rerun

Comment: it does not work, thanks again.

Comment: show me your code

Comment: ``` if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {  getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white)); }```

Comment: I use your code and his code below

Comment: Show your actual code, full class

Comment: I will edit the post

Answer (score 0):

Hello there you can do it dynamically in your activity

You can call this block of code in **onCreate**

```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);

        window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, resourceId));

 }
```

resourceId is your color id like `R.color.red`

Comment: you don't need flags

Comment: it can help you even on fragment if you don't need it is ok

Comment: you still don't need it in fragment.

Comment: ```if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)``` ??? Only above LOLLIPOP

Comment: yes you can target a great audience when you are pointing lollipop and greater

Comment: it is safe that and other wise if it is before version it will set your by default color

Comment: but still if you think it is really very necessary to add even in previous version you can create your different theme in style and call it on manifest activity tag ..  if you want this i can provide even this

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    if(getWindow()!=null){
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.color_amber));
    }
}
```

//final result
[image]

just create a sample project and use this code for verification